# Ruby, reorder an array based on another array?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to order `ary` according to the indices specified in `order`.

```
# Ruby
ary = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
order = [2, 3, 0, 1]

# Result I want
ary = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ary = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
order = [2, 3, 0, 1]

ary.values_at(*order)
  #=> ["c", "d", "a", "b"]
```

Comment: Can you explain what `*order` does? @Cary

Comment: `*`, the "splat" operator, converts `ary.values_at(*[2,3,0,1])` to `ary.values_at(2,3,0,1)`.  See the docs for [Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ary = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
order = [2, 3, 0, 1]
sorted_array = []

order.each do |i|
  sorted_array.push(ary[i])
end
```

Though looking at it, Cary's answer is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ary = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
order = [2, 3, 0, 1]

new_array = []

order.each do |index| #This returns the array you want.
    new_array << ary[index]
end
```

Comment: `<<` is the same as `push` when pushing a single value onto the end of an array.